# ConnectivityManager in Android L Preview

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, network-connection

My app checks for Network connection when starting.  In Android versions 2.3 thru 4.4 the below method works great (whether emulator or actual device).  On the Android L Preview Emulator, the method comes back false.

Here is my code:

```
// ===============================================================
public static boolean haveNetworkConnection(Context ctx) {

    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
    boolean haveConnectedEthernet = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {

        // String con = ni.isConnected() ? "Connected" : "Not Connected";

        if (!haveConnectedWifi) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
        }

        if (!haveConnectedMobile) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }

        if (!haveConnectedEthernet) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("ETHERNET"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedEthernet = true;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(ni.getTypeName()).append(" ").append(ni);


    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile
            || haveConnectedEthernet;
}
```

There is some weird `StringBuilder` stuff, I did not create this code -- it is in a project I inherited.  I have not needed to change anything since it works.  Does anyone know if there is any API changes with how `ConnectivityManager` works?  I checked the [API overview](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html) changes on the [dev site](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html) but did not see any relevant info on this.

Comment: what is the use of sb here?

Comment: @niteshgoel It's for logging that has been edited out.

Comment: There is no stable API for type names. Start by changing this to use NetworkInfo.getType() and verifying against ConnectivityManager.TYPE_* constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typename has been changed in L, for example should check "Cellular" instead of "MOBILE".